# Is it possible to achieve deferred & release payments with SagePay version 2.22?

Tags: payment, opayo

I need to know if this is possible with version 2.22. I know it works with version 2.23.

Also, does anyone have the pdf documentation for the 2.22 protocol version? As SagePay does not offer previous documentation files on their site.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question is yes.

Through Sage Pay, 2.22 is an older protocol version. Since then we have introduced v2.23 and [v3.00](http://www.sagepay.co.uk/support/find-an-integration-document). I have detailed the difference between v2.22, 2.23 and v3.00 at the end of this post.

Deferred and Release are available payment types (TxType=DEFERRED or TxType=RELEASE).

DEFERRED transactions.

By default a PAYMENT transaction type is used in your scripts to gain an authorisation from the bank, then settle that transaction early the following morning, committing the funds to be taken from your customer’s card.

In some cases you may not wish to take the funds from the card immediately, but merely place a “shadow” on their card to ensure they cannot subsequently spend those funds elsewhere, and then only take the money when you are ready to ship the goods. This type of transaction is called a DEFERRED transaction and is registered in exactly the same way as a normal PAYMENT. You just need to change your script to send a TxType of DEFERRED when you register the transaction (protocol A1) instead of PAYMENT.

DEFERRED transactions are NOT sent to the bank for completion the following morning. In fact, they are not sent at all until you RELEASE them by logging into the VSP Admin interface, finding the transaction and clicking the Release button.

If you are unable to fulfil the order, you can also ABORT deferred transactions in a similar manner and the customer will never be charged.

DEFERRED transactions work well in situations where it is only a matter of days between the customer ordering and you being ready to ship. Ideally all DEFERRED transaction should be released within 6 days (according to card scheme rules). After that the shadow may disappear from the card before you settle the transaction, you will have no guarantee that you’ll receive the funds if the user has maxed out their card in the mean time. If you regularly require longer than 6 days to fulfil orders, you should consider using AUTHENTICATE and AUTHORISE instead of DEFERRED payments (see below)
DEFERRED transactions remain available for RELEASE for up to 30 days. After that time they are automatically ABORTed by the Sage Pay system.

If you haven't already, please make sure Deferred is a payment type on your Sage Pay account. You can either call our Support team on 0845 111 4455 or email support@sagepay.com to check. The reason I say this is because if you send the TxType=DEFERRED to Sage Pay without having Deferred as a payment type on your Sage Pay account, you will get a 4006 error. A 4006 error means the payment type does not exist on your Sage Pay account. To resolve this, ask Support to add it onto your vendor account.

**Differences between Sage Pay protocols;**

The main difference with protocol 2.22 and 2.23 is the splitting of the name (first name, surname) and address (address1, address2, city).  Also protocol 2.23 has new fields to handle additions functionality such as PayPal, Server Low Profile and Partner Referral IDs - please note that Server Low Profile and Partner Referral IDs are not applicable to you if you use a Form integration.

Mandatory fields v3.00:

- Debit MasterCard – (MCDEBIT) – mandatory for Mastercard Debit cards. Sent in CardType
- FraudResponse – if use ReD mandatory otherwise optional
- Refund Security Key – sent in the VPSSignature response – need to be able to handle
- Decline Codes – sent in the VPSSignature response – if using API, need to know 2 digit  decline codes from bank
- Expiry Date – sent in the VPSSignature response (Form and Server only) mandatory
- BillingPostCode and DeliveryPostCode fields are mandatory fields
- Attempt Only Status – check 3DSecureStatus field. Sent in the VPSSignature response

Optional fields v3.00:

- Additional XML Fields – CustomerXML and BasketXML fields
- TRIP Data – sent in the BasketXML field
- Website Reference
- Surcharge
- Token – CreateToken field is mandatory for v3.0 but the [Token guide](http://www.sagepay.co.uk/file/1171/download-document/sagepaytokensystemprotocolandintegrationguidelinev3.0_0.pdf?token=dVS1xZit6iCdtxLgHQSBA7V6og6soZri4XKo2mdPlCs) available is only for v2.23
- Vendor Data Field
- FraudResponse – if use ReD mandatory otherwise optional
- CardType – sent in the VPSSignature response. If you have a dedicated merchant number for PPro payments you would use this otherwise optional
- 3DSecureStatus field - Attempt Only Status is sent in the VPSSignature response – optional if you have 3D Secure turned off
- PayPal Basket – Basket can be sent to PayPal
- Formatted Basket – can send BasketXML in place of Basket field